# Using Symfony 1.4 sfGuardUser tables with Symfony 2 SecurityBundle?

Tags: php, symfony, symfony1, symfony-1.4, sfguard

I am trying to migrate a part of a software system to Symfony 2. I can't possible migrate all of them at once, so, I am looking for a way to use sf_guard_ tables for authentication/authorization in Symfony 2. Is this possible?

I have done this so far: http://www.propelorm.org/cookbook/symfony2/the-symfony2-security-component-and-propel.html

I think the current issue is that the hashing scheme (that involves the use of a salt) does not work the same way and also that the role/permission system is different.

Comment: Can you add the hash/salt specification for Symfony 1.4 sefGuard and the one in use with the symfony2 component to your question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest you use FOS User Bundle https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSUserBundle. Great documentation and in active development.